# Prolog reasoning about predicates

Tags: prolog, metaprogramming, meta-predicate

Assume someone wrote the following huge list of clauses:

```
loves(me, wife).
loves(me, dog).
loves(wife, dog).
hates(me, enemy).
attracts(iron, magnet).
...
```

Now I want to automatically generate reciprocal clauses given some higher-order predicate and rule similar to:

```
reciprocal([loves, hates, attracts, ...]).
some_conclusion :- some_premises.
```

so that I have the following expected result:

```
?- loves(wife, me).
true.
```

To keep things simple, I ignored the list argument and instead defined the simple clause `reciprocal(loves).` with some complex rule using `reciprocal(X)`, but I can't seem to `assert` a rule with success.

I've tried different variations and orderings of

```
assert(
    Y :- (reciprocal(P), Y =.. [P, B, A], X =.. [P, A, B], call(X))
).
```

or (to add the deduced clauses themselves)

```
assert(Y), reciprocal(P), Y =.. [P, B, A], X =.. [P, A, B], call(X)
```

but I've only got `false` or errors like `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated` using SWI-Prolog.

My question is (obviously): how can I make this rule work? I don't care whether the rule is part of the database or just a preprocessor to add the actual clauses to the database (although the former would be preferable), I just want to learn how to reason about predicates (i.e. how to use higher-order predicates).

*Note: I've learned logic programming since a month only, and I want to try out some ideas from Notation3 and N-triples etc.*

---

**EDIT:**

The missing part, the absolute cherry on the cake, is some dynamic solution using a rule similar to

```
Y :- (reciprocal(P), call(P, A, B), Y =.. [P, B, A]).
```

If anyone has some solution for this one, please post it!

Comment: First, try to get acquainted with `call/N` with `N > 1`. For example you may replace `X =.. [P, A, B], call(X)` by `call(P, A, B)` &ct

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to add clauses one by one to the database as such (MVP):

```
?- [user].
|: loves(me, wife).
|: loves(me, dog).
|: loves(wife, dog).
|: reciprocal(loves).
|: (Ctrl-Z)

?- dynamic loves/2   %! seems necessary for next clause...
true.

?- reciprocal(P), X =.. [P, A, B], Y =.. [P, B, A], assert(X :- (Y, !)).
P = loves,
X = loves(A, B),
Y = loves(B, A).

?- loves(wife, me).
true.
```

It seems I didn't arrange the 'rule' in this way which is procedurally sound.

Now I'll focus on `findall` to avoid requiring user input (the `;` after each solution for `P`).

---

**EDIT:**

I completed all but one feature... Given a file `db.pl` containing

```
loves(me, wife).
loves(me, dog).
loves(wife, dog).
attracts(iron, magnets).
```

and a file `rules.pl` containing

```
reciprocal([
    loves,
    attracts
]).
parse_reciprocal([]).
parse_reciprocal([H|T]) :- 
    X =.. [H, A, B], Y =.. [H, B, A], dynamic(H/2), assert(X :- (Y, !)),
    parse_reciprocal(T).

:- initialization reciprocal(L), parse_reciprocal(L).
```

I succeed at my first goal

```
?- [db].
true.

?- [rules].
true.

?- loves(dog, wife).
true.

?- attracts(magnets, iron).
true.
```

The missing part, the absolute cherry on the cake, is some dynamic solution using a rule similar to

```
Y :- (reciprocal(P), call(P, A, B), Y =.. [P, B, A]).
```